# Как создать проект на angular2 если глобально установлен Angular 6?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular-cli

Приложение должно быть с интерфейсом командной строки(CLI). Пробовал устанавливать cli@1.0.0 - в итоге проект был на angular 4.4.7, можно как-то установить второй, может даже с удалением глобальной версии.

Comment: непонятен вопрос, конкретизируйте пожалуйста, какого результата вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался. Нужно было сделать даунгрейд ангудара с 6 на 2